# Graphql type resolver by id

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to get familiar with Graphql by building a server with the following schema:

```
type Game
{
    id: ID!
    players: [Player!]!
    winner: Player
    ...
}

type Player {
    id: ID!
    game: Game!
    ...
}

type Query {
    getGame(id: ID!): Game
    getPlayer(id: ID!): Player
}
```

And map to the following data:

```
const games = {
    1: {
        id: 1,
        players: [2, 3],
        winner: undefined
    }
};
const players = {
    2: {
        id: 2,
        game: 1
    },
    3: {
        id: 3,
        game: 1
    },
};
```

While writing the resolvers, I noticed a lot of boilerplate code - I had to write conceptually the same field resolver for every object member which holds a foreign key.

```
const typedefs = {
    Query: {
        getGame: (_, {id}) => games[id],
        getPlayer: (_, {id}) => players[id]
    },
    Game: {
        winner: (game) => players[game.winner],
        players: (game) => game.players.map(id => players[id])
    },
    Player: {
        game: (player) => games[player.id]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create a type resolver by ID?
for example, a `Player` field or query would always be resolved by `(id) => players[id]`,
and a game field or query would always be resolved by `(id) => games[id]`.

I saw that this is achievable using AWS-Amplify's `@model` directive, but I'm wondering if there is a more standard way I'm missing rather than implementing my own directive.

Is this a feature of any current Graphql implementation? I couldn't find anything that resembles it in apollo-graphql's documentation (or in graphql-js's).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of changing the default resolver. Apollo-GraphQL just passes the resolver map to `graphql-tools` and `graphql-tools` uses `graphql-js`. `graphql-js` implements the default resolver [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/7e79bbe5f2b0e971b5e5f6fe3e7b19c43dea9f35/src/execution/execute.js#L1203) and uses it [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/7e79bbe5f2b0e971b5e5f6fe3e7b19c43dea9f35/src/execution/execute.js#L362).

Maybe you could try using ES2015 `Proxy` to provide a default implementation for resolvers in the object instead. But even if you override your default resolver, you break all the places where you used the actual default resolver.